# Changing iOS app template

Tags: ios, templates, ios5, ios6, master-detail

I have an app which I developed by picking "Empty application" when I started off. But now I want to change its template from empty to "Master Detail" like the Facebook, Google+ or Hike apps. Is there a straightforward method to do this or do I have to start from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Once the project has been created the template that was used to create it means nothing. It is just used to seed the project with files. Therefore, you could create a "Master-Detail Application", delete the extra frameworks, controllers, and views, and now have an "Empty Application".

The reverse is also true. You could either add the controllers or views that you now want, or you could create a second project. Once you have the second project, it may be easier to bring your current code into that project or learn from the second project and bring that into your current one.